# jQuery when slider is clicked

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a function that is triggered when the slider is slided. But not clicked.

```
$('#slider1, #slider2, #slider3, #slider4, #slider5').bind('slide', function (event, ui)
{ some huge code.
```

How do I call this function also when the sliders are clicked on. I have tried.

I have tried this:

```
$('#slider1, #slider2, #slider3, #slider4, #slider5').bind('slide, click', function (event, ui)
{ some huge code.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do it without the ','

```
$('#slider1, #slider2, #slider3, #slider4, #slider5').bind('slide click', function (event, ui)
{ some huge code.
```